# Rails additional patch routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have CRUD already, and I want to add an additional Patch route, like this:

```
PATCH    /searches/:id(.:format)                                              searches#update

PATCH    /searches/sync(.:format)                                       searches/sync#perform
```

However, when I do api calls, it always return an error that says

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Search with 'id'=sync)`

Any ideas?

sync_controller

```
module Searches

  class SyncController < ApplicationController

    def perform
      search_ids = params[:search_ids]&.keys&.map { |key| params[:search_ids][key] } || []
      outcome = SearchSync.run(search_ids: search_ids, user: current_user)
      if outcome.success?
        render json: outcome.result
      else
        render json: outcome.errors.symbolic, status: 422
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Routes

```
resources :searches, only: [:index, :update, :destroy]
namespace :searches do
  patch '/sync', to: 'sync#perform'
end
```

Comment: I think you have any before_filters to load @search object in controller which called ?

Comment: can you add your controller code?

Comment: hmmm But both SearchController and SyncController have no before_filter in it

Comment: and also my application_controller, have nothing to do with the search :/

Comment: can you share sync action code ?

Comment: and routes you defined

Comment: just added it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to rename namespace from '**searches**' to something else because its conflicting with **resources :searches**. If you don't want to change then you've to declare namespace above resources :searches.

Second, I doubt that PATCH is the right method in this case because PATCH should be used where there is an existing resource and we need to update it partially.

Comment: Thanks man
Btw, I am updating the user_id for the searches (but will only receive an array of ids)  that is already exist in db

Comment: ok, did you tried by renaming namespace 'searches'? or replacing its position with resources :searches ?